# Use JavaScript to print HTML page in landscape format

Tags: javascript

I want to use JavaScript to print an HTML page in the landscape format.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, that's not possible, your page will be printed how it is made. Having said that, you can use CSS to make your page in landscape view.

```
@page {
   size: landscape;
}
```

As for IE, check out this post:

- [using css to force Landscape Print in IE](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/HTML/Landscape_Print_in_IE.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"    type="text/javascript"></script><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">    function JPrint(){
     // Create the WScript
     var objWScriptShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
     // Send Keys
     objWScriptShell.SendKeys("(%f)u");
      // Change to landscape
     objWScriptShell.SendKeys("(%a)");
     objWScriptShell.SendKeys("~");       
// Enter O.K.
     setTimeout("window.print()",500);  
}</script><input onclick="javascript:void(JPrint())" type="button" value="Print Page"/>
```

Comment: Some explanation would have been nice.